# javascript (promise) puzzle

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

How would you write the following code if you had to use Promises?

The idea is that a "private" method `p1` makes a call to a function that does something asynchronous and then, when the result of the asynchronous call is ready, the control is passed to the "private" method `p2`. Just like `p1`, `p2` makes a call to a function that executes some asynchronous stuff and then, the control is passed back to `p1`. In this example, this keeps going forever.

As you can imagine I have boiled down my code to a more theoretical scenario to make it short. In practice, `p1` and `p2` are doing two different things and based on some conditions in `p1` and `p2` the program execution do stop.

```
mySimpleRunner = (function () {

  var service = {}; 

  var async = function (cb) {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
      cb(n);
    }, n); 
  }

  var p1 = function (r) {
    async(p2);
    console.log("1:", r || "first call");
  };  

  var p2 = function (r) {
    async(p1);
    console.log("2:", r); 
  };  

  service.run = function () {
    p1();
  }

  return service;

})();

mySimpleRunner.run();
```

I have tried many possible ways to do the same with Promises, where instead of passing the function `cb` to async, async is a Promise that resolves when the timer is done. But I haven't figured out how to do this properly.

If you have sometime and you want to give it a try, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a whole lot of difference really. The only thing is that you pass the callback to `then` instead if `async`:

```
function async() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, n), n);
    });
}

function p1(r) {
    async().then(p2);
    console.log(r);
}

function p2(r) {
    async().then(p1);
    console.log(r);
}
```

Comment: FYI, `function () { resolve(n); }` would do the same thing.